# Rapsbian and Qt5

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, qt5

I'm developing an application using qt5.11 on Raspberry Pi 3. My code works on my laptop with ubuntu 18.xx. When I put my code on the RPi, I can compile it with the Makefile `make -j2` but when I want to launch my program I get the following message:

```
16:02:44: Starting /home/pi/build-VideoProcessor-Desktop-Debug/VideoProcessor...
**libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate**
**qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin**

(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:02:55.208: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 16:02:55.208: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable'
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
(VideoProcessor:985): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:02:55.208: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
```

I don't understand what's going on with my RPi because my code works with my laptop.

Comment: Are you using GTK styles?

Comment: key ! i don't kown. my code works with ubuntu 18.xx and not with raspbian last distro. How can i find this information if i am using gtk style ? thanks

Comment: Its a little bit of a hack but you can install gtk on your Pi.  type  `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`

Comment: Also check out this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/910012/how-can-i-get-qt5-applications-to-use-the-gtk-theme-in-ubuntu-17-04

Answer (score 1):

I believe this problem is because you do not have OpenGL support enabled.

Run:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then pick:

```
Advanced Options
GL Driver
GL (Fake KMS)
```

That should make things work after a reboot.

This will eliminate this error : libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate.